# How to shift elements in an array 1 over?

Tags: java

I want to shift all the elements in this array by 1: [1 4 9 16 25] where the last element (25) becomes the first element. My problem is that I keep getting the array to just print out [25 1 1 1 1], how do I fix this?

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class question4 {
public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] array = new int[5];
    array[0] = 1;
    array[1] = 4;
    array[2] = 9;
    array[3] = 16;
    array[4] = 25;
    ShiftNumbers(array);
    System.out.print(Arrays.toString(array));
}
public static void ShiftNumbers(int[] array){
    int temp = array[array.length-1];
    for(int i=0; i<=array.length-2; i++){
        array[i+1]=array[i];
    }
    array[0] = temp;        



}
```

}

Comment: Try working backwards from the end, rather than forwards from the beginning.  Otherwise, you'll just copy the same value all the way along.

Comment: Do you want to do this in-place (with one array) or are you okay with using multiple arrays?  The latter approach becomes *incredibly* straightforward, but neither is difficult.

Comment: thank you! I didn't realize it overwrote the values while in the loop like that.

Comment: @EvanZ Try to debug the code, hopefully you will find the error by yourself

Answer (score 1):

**Updated the answer to give a fully working solution** rather than just guidance, based on the comment from Sotirios Delimanolis.

With `System.arrayCopy`, you can easily do it in 3 steps.

```
public static int[] revisedShiftNumbers(int[] array) {
    int[] newArr = new int[array.length];
    System.arraycopy(array, 0, newArr, 1, array.length - 1);
    newArr[0]=array[array.length-1];
    return newArr;
}
```

And then call this method as `int[] shiftedArray = revisedShiftNumbers(array);`

The method takes five arguments:

1. `src`: The source array.
2. `srcPosition`: The position in the source from where you wish to begin
   copying.
3. `des`: The destination array.
4. `desPosition`: The position in the destination array to where the copy
   should start.
5. `length`: The number of elements to be copied.

Comment: I wonder who downvoted this but this is the most efficient way.

Comment: @Enzokie I wonder who upvoted this, because the code presented throws an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. It also shifts in the opposite direction requested.

Comment: @Sotirios, you are not getting the essence of the solution. The intention is not to present a code that the OP can plug in his code and it starts working without any additional efforts. The idea was to suggest using `System.arrayCopy` to achieve the op's objective.

Comment: Then put it with an example that works or remove it altogether. However, without it, you essentially just copied the javadoc which is pretty useless in describing a solution.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, see the updates now. It is a fully working solution now.

Comment: You're still shifting in the wrong direction: _where the last element (25) becomes the first element_.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is when you loop from the beginning of the array it would overwrite all the rest of the value, i suggest going from the end of the array to the start of the array when overwriting the array values.
Try this:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class question4 {
public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] array = new int[5];
    array[0] = 1;
    array[1] = 4;
    array[2] = 9;
    array[3] = 16;
    array[4] = 25;
    ShiftNumbers(array);
    System.out.print(Arrays.toString(array));
}
public static void ShiftNumbers(int[] array){
    int temp = array[array.length-1];
    for(int i=array.length-2; i>=0; i--){
        array[i+1]=array[i];
    }
    array[0] = temp;        

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that inside `for loop` you are overwriting the next value with current value which gives you `25 1 1 1 1`. Since all other values are lost(overwritten).

Now here's my way of doing this particular problem by using modular arithmetic.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class question4 {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] array = {1, 4, 9, 16, 25};
        ShiftNumbers(array);
        System.out.print(Arrays.toString(array));
    }

    public static void ShiftNumbers(int[] array){

        int last = array[0];
        int temp;
        int length = array.length;

        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){

             temp = array[(i+1)%length];
             array[(i+1)%length] = last;
             last = temp;

        }
        array[0] = temp;        

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Other solution. Using linkedList. :-)

```
public class ShiftSimple {
    private static int mTestCnt = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = new int[5];
        array[0] = 1;
        array[1] = 4;
        array[2] = 9;
        array[3] = 16;
        array[4] = 25;

        shiftNumbers(array);
        printNumbers(array);

        shiftNumbers(array);
        printNumbers(array);

        shiftNumbers(array);
        printNumbers(array);
    }

    public static void shiftNumbers(int[] array) {
        LinkedList<Integer> linkedList = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        for(int item : array) {
            linkedList.add(item);
        }
        linkedList.push(linkedList.pollLast());     // shift last to first

        int i = 0;
        for(int item : linkedList) {
            array[i++] = item;
        }
    }

    public static void printNumbers(int[] array) {
        System.out.println("["+ ++mTestCnt +"] Check Numbers");
        for(int i : array) {
            System.out.println(">> " + i);
        }
    }
}
```

**[OUTPUT]**

```
[1] Check Numbers
>> 25
>> 1
>> 4
>> 9
>> 16
[2] Check Numbers
>> 16
>> 25
>> 1
>> 4
>> 9
[3] Check Numbers
>> 9
>> 16
>> 25
>> 1
>> 4
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = new int[5];
    array[0] = 1;
    array[1] = 4;
    array[2] = 9;
    array[3] = 16;
    array[4] = 25;

    ReverseArray(array);
    System.out.print(Arrays.toString(array));
}

public static void ReverseArray(int[] a) {
    int size, i, j, temp;
    size = a.length;

    for( i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
         a[i] = a[i];
    }

   j = i - 1;     // now j will point to the last element
   i = 0;         // and i will point to the first element

   while(i<j)
   {
       temp = a[i];
       a[i] = a[j];
       a[j] = temp;
       i++;
       j--;
   }

   System.out.print("\n Now the Reverse of Array is : \n");
   for(i=0; i<size; i++)
   {
       System.out.print(a[i]+ "  ");
   }
}
```